# Write a complete line into a text file

Tags: r, file, text, line

I'm creating a summary file for the output of the script I'm working on. I want to be able to write all the following line (for example) into a text file, or at least to be able to write all the parameters I specified inside the function I used (in the following example I used `subset()` so I want to be able to write which parameters I inserted inside `subset()`)  :

```
ac.data <- subset(r.data, subject != 99 & rt > 100 & rt < 2000)  # Accuracy
```

Does anyone know how can I do this?

Comment: What should the file output look like?

Comment: You can use `cat`. For example `cat("myoutput\n", file = "myfile.txt", append = TRUE)` will add the word myoutput to the file specified followed by a new line.

Comment: Hi Thomas. The output should be: ac.data <- subset(r.data, subject != 99 & rt > 100 & rt < 2000)  # Accuracy

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly and you want to write your function into a text file, this should do it:

```
write("ac.data <- subset(r.data, subject != 99 & rt > 100 & rt < 2000)  # Accuracy",file="C:\\R\\out.txt")
```

Comment: Hi Juergen. Thank you for your answer. However I want to be able to write all the following line (for example) into a text file, or at least to be able to write all the parameters I specified inside the function without copying and pasting the line each time to the write function. The line I want to write will not be the same and I don't want to manually copy and paste it into the write function each time I run my script.